# how do I merge these objects to make a json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I merge these two objects.  The merge function won't combine them.

```
var $exID = $('#exDIV input');
var values = {};
$exID.each(function(i, el) {
    values[$(el).attr("id")] = $(el).val();
});

var actionData = $.merge(values, { "tableID" : "exTable" });
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: What version of jQuery? Unless it's > 1.4, this won't work as in previous versions `$.merge()` expects true javascript arrays.

Comment: I am using 1.4.4.  It wouldn't work for me.  I think $.extend should do what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with two objects, not arrays. Use `$.extend` instead of `$.merge`.

Comment: It's better to use `$.extend()`, but `$.merge()` will also work on objects in jQuery 1.4+.

Comment: It will work on *some* objects. Not all, since it is trying to treat them as "arraylike", AFAIK. In particular, the OP's example clearly does not work.